# Retrofit2 and Moshi: unable to read accented letters

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, moshi

I have Retrofit2 and Moshi inside my Android project for read json response i receive from some webservice. 
I have noticed that i'm not able to read correctly accented letters inside json response, for example if a json field value contains

**ü**

that letter is parsed as

**�**

This is how i initialize Retrofit (i'm using dagger)

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASEURL)
        .addConverterFactory(
            MoshiConverterFactory.create(
                Moshi.Builder().add(SingleToArrayAdapter.INSTANCE).build()
            ).asLenient()
        )
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build()
}
```

And *SingleToArrayAdapter* is a custom adapter.

Comment: Check if this is properly encoded on server side first (ie by querying manually) as this smells as encoding issue

Comment: I don't have access to server. But if i open service url from browser i can see the correct ü character

Comment: This is not correct test. You need to request by hand, inspect returned headers and returned raw content. What browser shows may not be the same what API returned.